# getting Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."

Tags: php, sql, swift

I am getting this error when i try to insert data in my SQL database through php in swift

I'm not sure why i'm getting this error. I'm new to swift and really stuck on this situation

error im getting:

```
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." 
 UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

here is my swift code

```
     let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/userRegister.php");
        let request =   NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

        let postString = "email=\(username)&password=\(password)&firstName=\(firstName)"

        print(postString)


        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){

            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json{
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as! String!
                    print("result:\(resultValue)")

                    var isUserRegistered: Bool = false;
                    if(resultValue == "success"){
                        isUserRegistered = true;
                    }
                    var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    if (!isUserRegistered)
                    {
                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in

                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
                        };

                        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
                        }


                    )};


            } catch { print(error)}
        }

        task.resume();
```

and my php:

```
$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$firstName = htmlentities($_POST["firstName"]);§

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password,$firstName);

if($result) 
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return; 
}

public function registerUser($email, $password, $firstName)
{
$sql = "insert into users set username=?, password=?,firstName=?";
$statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

if (!$statement)
throw new Exception($statement->error);

$statement->bind_param("sss", $email, $password, $firstName);
$returnValue = $statement->execute();

return $returnValue;
}
```

}

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure your php script returns valid json data? You can try calling your script from poster and check whether it returns valid json response.

Comment: it does respond, because it works when i try to send username and password only, to insert only the username and password (removed $firstname as parameter), however i want to send the first name also but i get this error.

Comment: the error occurs after this line                   let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary